# Actionbaractivity unfortunately application has stopped

Tags: android, themes

I wanted to create an Andriod 2.1 compatible action bar and imported the android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity package. I exended the MainActivity class to ActionBarActivity and now after running the application I keep getting an "Unfortunately  application has stopped".
I attach the main class code.
Thanks for the help,
Nitzan

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}
```

and the logcat:

```
01-02 16:21:15.900: D/AndroidRuntime(792): Shutting down VM
01-02 16:21:15.900: W/dalvikvm(792): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3abbb90)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792): Process: com.theredpill.myfirstapp, PID: 792
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.theredpill.myfirstapp/com.theredpill.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:111)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at com.theredpill.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
01-02 16:21:15.960: E/AndroidRuntime(792):  ... 11 more
01-02 16:20:01.225: I/Process(792): Sending signal. PID: 792 SIG: 9
```

and the xml from AndroidManifest.xml contains the following theme tag:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.theredpill.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.theredpill.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.theredpill.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>`

Comment: post your entire manifest xml

Comment: Hi Greg, see above. TX !

Comment: This doesnt seem possible

Comment: Where does it go wrong ?